# Python3 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'clear'

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, attributeerror, python-3.2

I am working on a Linux machine with Python version 3.2.3. 
Whenever I try to do `list.clear()` I get an exception

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> l.clear()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'clear'
```

At the same time on my Mac with Python 3.4.3 the same code runs smoothly. 
Can it be due to the difference between Python versions or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`list.clear` was added in Python 3.3.

Citing the [*Mutable Sequence Types*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=clear#mutable-sequence-types) section in the documentation:

> *New in version 3.3*: `clear()` and `copy()` methods.
>
> `s.clear()` removes all items from `s` (same as `del s[:]`)

See the [issue #10516](http://bugs.python.org/issue10516) for the relevant discussion and alternative ways of clearing lists. In summary, it is the same as `del l[:]` and `l[:] = []`.

Comment: Just adding that you can use `del l[:]` instead.

Comment: Thanks!
@dav1d Thanks, yes, that's what I did.